# How to correctly write a SQL statement that change the data type from varchar to date and set the new value of this field using the original value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not so into database and I have the following problem.

I am using PostgreSQL and I have the following situation: I have a table named `striep` containing a column `periodo_da` that is a `varchar` of 6 characters that can contain only the following data: `202001` or `202101` or `202201` where the first 4 digits represents an year and the last two digits represents a month (January).

I have to implement a SQL code having the following behavior:

1. Change the `periodo_da` column from `varchar` to a `date` type.
2. As value set the first of January of the year.

I have tried to do in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE striep
    ALTER COLUMN periodo_da TYPE DATE USING to_date(periodo_da, 'YYYYMMDD');

UPDATE striep
SET periodo_da = CASE 
                    WHEN periodo_da = '202001' THEN '2020-01-01'::date
                    WHEN periodo_da = '202101' THEN '2021-01-01'::date
                    WHEN periodo_da = '202301' THEN '2022-01-01'::date
                    ELSE NULL 
                 END;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "202001"
LINE 6:                     WHEN periodo_da = '202001' THEN '2020-01...
                                              ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
SQL state: 22008
Character: 169
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly implement this behavior?

Comment: You don't need to do the UPDATE, the ALTER COLUMN ... USING already did that: `select to_date('202001', 'YYYYMMDD'); 01/01/2020`. The issue is the implied `select '202001'::date; ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "202001" ... HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.` in the UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to compare a string (which does not match the default Postgres date format) with a date type column.

So, you can write your `UPDATE` query in this manner:

```sql
UPDATE striep
SET periodo_da = CASE 
    WHEN periodo_da = TO_DATE('202001', 'YYYYMM') THEN '2020-01-01'::date
    WHEN periodo_da = TO_DATE('202101', 'YYYYMM') THEN '2021-01-01'::date
    WHEN periodo_da = TO_DATE('202301', 'YYYYMM') THEN '2022-01-01'::date
    ELSE NULL 
END;
```

Or in much better form:

```
UPDATE striep
SET periodo_da = CASE 
    WHEN periodo_da = '2020-01-01'::date THEN '2020-01-01'::date
    WHEN periodo_da = '2021-01-01'::date THEN '2021-01-01'::date
    WHEN periodo_da = '2023-01-01'::date THEN '2022-01-01'::date
    ELSE NULL 
END;
```

See working example on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6197LEFY)

Comment: More to the point you don't have to do  it all. `... DATE USING to_date(periodo_da, 'YYYYMMDD')` will already have done the conversion.

Comment: Very minor correction. Date format should be 'yyyymm'. So `USING to_date(periodo_da, 'YYYYMM')`.